# Prebuilt Python Caffe for OSX

Tags: python, macos, caffe, pycaffe

Is there any pre-built PyCaffe out there for OSX? I do see instructions on how to build it but I'm sure I'll have a lot of difficulties trying to build all of its dependencies. So, I'd appreciate it anyone knows where I can get the prebuilt PyCaffe module? Or is it necessary that it gets fully built on the machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case you're familiar with [docker](https://www.docker.com/), you could try: https://github.com/ryankennedyio/deep-dream-generator

On OS X, you'll need to have [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) or some such.

Anyway, I was able to get up and running in under 5 minutes or so with this approach, after spending an hour or so (and giving up) downloading/building/installing dependencies directly.